# How can I alert supported EcmaScript version of the browser?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-5

Is there a way to alert the supported EcmaScript version of the current environment where I run my JavaScript?

Comment: Do feature tests for the features you care about, don't care about the actual browser, or the ecma version. You never know if an implementation is correct or complete anyway, even if they would claim "ecma XYZ".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Short answer**: No.

**Long answer**: First of all, browsers doesn't implement ECMAScript but a language based on that specification (e.g. JavaScript for Firefox, JScript for Microsoft). Often, they can implement part of the standard, and complete the standard in a next version of the language (it happened in JavaScript 1.8 / 1.8.1 / 1.8.5 about ES5 for example, see [New in JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/New_in_JavaScript)).

Plus, they could anticipate the standard: see [for...of](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) or [let](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let), that Mozilla has since years, that are part of ES6.

So, you can't really say what ES version is supported by your environment; what you can do is testing the functionality you are interested in, and use them. In most of the case, we apply a shim, where is possible, to emulate that functionality, like for [ES5](https://github.com/kriskowal/es5-shim).