# In JavaScript, is there more proper function for information pop-up than alert()?

Tags: javascript, messagebox

I want to inform user about successful ajax request by a javascript information pop-up box.

Alert does what I want, but from semantic point of view it has more of a warning purpose.

Confirm and prompt are for different purpose too.

Is there semanticly more proper information box than alert? E.g. something like `MsgBox()` ?

Comment: [`confirm`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/confirm)? Other than that, most folk use a third party (usually non-blocking) solution.

Comment: With "from semantic point of view it has more of a warning purpose" do you mean it should be used only for errors (and not in case of successful operations)? May I ask why? The operation you want to confirm only requires an "ok" button which is exactly what alert() does.

Comment: We have to write our own css code for this . I have tried below link for my application .It might be useful for you.  http://www.sevensignature.com/blog/code/pure-css-popup-without-javascript/

Comment: On the other hand if you want a more "powerful" way to personalize your messages, the solution is probably to use an external tool like the dialog in jqueryui.

Comment: @AmarnadhMeda & #nowhere thanks, but I want to use javascript-pure pop-up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Javascript providing a semantic message to the user is a misnomer. Messaging should be handled by HTML.

Others here are recommending third party solutions for 'message boxes' but IMO that does not answer your question. There is no semantic information popup box in javascript besides `alert`, `confirm`, and `prompt`.

The alert box is part of the browser environment, and is actually part of the window object, which is provided by the browser. For this reason alert,prompt,confirm [aren't even native to EcmaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14747171/how-can-i-alert-supported-ecmascript-version-of-the-browser)

So if you want a semantic way to inform a user, then you use semantic markup in HTML, and have the content revealed using javascript via DOM manipulation, whether its written by yourself or with plugin suggestions as others have written.

Answer (score 2):

You should definitely try [SweetAlert](http://t4t5.github.io/sweetalert/)!

The syntax is almost identical to the normal `alert` but it looks awesome and has much more flexibility.

Example of using in an AJAX request:

```
swal({
    title: "Ajax request example",
    text: "Submit to run ajax request",
    type: "info",
    showCancelButton: true,
    closeOnConfirm: false,
    showLoaderOnConfirm: true,
},
function(){
    setTimeout(function(){
        swal("Ajax request finished!");
    }, 2000);
});
```

Shows:

[image: ajax]

Answer (score 1):

I am using noty for this purpuse:
http://ned.im/noty/

```
composer require needim/noty
```

or

```
bower install noty
```

Answer (score 1):

Most of the time, a modal window **inside** the current page, instead of `window.alert` or `window.confirm` which was misused so many times that browsers have a tendency to block them.

You can develop your own, or use a component from one of the many js/css libraries out there.

For instance you can use twitter bootstrap's modal: http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals looks like this, but there are many others:
[image]

You can also use simple notification boxes on one corner of the page if you don't want to interrupt your user's flow on the web app.

An example is https://notifyjs.com/ which looks like this:

[image]